# opening EDB file in matlab or python

Tags: python, matlab, edb

I have EDB files with raw data that I need to analyze for an experiment. The data is a recording of digital handwriting that was collected through a digital smartpen. I managed to open the file in File Viewer but it only allows viewing it, not editing.
Is there a function or any other way to open EDB files in Matlab or Python? 
Many Thanks!

Comment: wtf is an [edb](http://file.org/extension/edb)?  A microsoft exchange file in "b-tree structure" apparently.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Iron Python and CLR, check out ManagedEsent and Esedb.

http://managedesent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Esedb/

C Documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg269259(v=exchg.10).aspx

Comment: Python documentation isn't available anymore :(
http://managedesent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Esedb/
Do you have any alternatives please?